# I cannot use Angular 5 as OpaqueToken has been removed

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-flex-layout

I've updated my angular 4 project to angular 5.2x. While building the app it keeps throwing

> @angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'.
>   error.

I've already tried so many suggestions from github but still this having the same error again and again.

```
npm uninstall @angular/flex-layout
```

then delete node_modules

```
npm i

npm i @angular/flex-layout@latest
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `InectionToken`

Comment: are you using OpaqueToken anywhere in the code?

Comment: Yes it was imported from @angular/core and now I've changed it to InjectionToken. @Aluan tnx alot

Comment: @Scados no problem.

Comment: But why am I getting `OpaqueToken is not a constructor` error in the console?

Comment: For angular 5, you'll need to use a version 5 of flex-layout, not 2